# In batch file after 'for loop' it is not executing 'if else' statement

Tags: batch-processing

There are several files in a folder like

```
abc-xyz-1-01022017
abc-xyz-2-01022017
abc-xyz-1-02022017
```

etc. I am iterating through all this files and I checking user entered date `%1` with date in file name like 01022017. For loop executing well but after that it's not checking the condition. Here is my code

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=-." %%a in ('dir /b D:\NewFolder *-*-*-*.*') do echo set filename=%%a-%%b-%1 set date=%%d 
IF [%1]==%date% (echo "same date") else (echo "different date")
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you are simply appending command after command separated with a
  space they aren't necessarily executed.
- You could append commands with a `&` or put them into a (code block)
  surrounded by parentheses.
- The for vars are only valid following the do on the same line or
  inside the same code block.
- comparing several files can't have a single result, so the echo should contain the file it is referring to.
- comparing a date inside brackets with a date without  brackets will always fail.

Just a try to guess what you may have meant:

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=-." %%a in (
  'dir /b D:\NewFolder\*-*-*-*.*'
) do (
  IF [%1]==[%%d] (
    echo same date       %1 -- %%a-%%b-%%c-%%d.%%e
  ) else (
    echo different date  %1 -- %%a-%%b-%%c-%%d.%%e
  )
)
```